# Retrofit rxJava does not invoke onError for 500 internal server errors

Tags: android, retrofit2

On android, I make server calls through retrofit and the server can sometimes return a 500 response.

Is there a reason why onError does not get invoked in the subscriber?

```
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<Void>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if (isViewAttached()) {
                        getView().onError(e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<Void> response) {
                    response.code() <-- why would 500 here not get routed to the onError instead?
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

This depends part on your configuration and part on how you defined your call, but it will all boil down to one of 2 `Observables`.

If you look at the source code you can see that if your call returns a type of `Response<Foo>` Retrofit will internally create either a  `CallEnqueueObservable<Foo>` or `CallExecuteObservable` for your call. Check it out in the [adapt](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/mhttps://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/RxJava2CallAdapter.javaain/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/RxJava2CallAdapter.java) method. For RxJava 1 this is similar, but the observables are called differently. Anyway, internally the way things work are quite the same. The call is executed and `onNext` is called with a `response` instance.

If you take a look at how this works inside `Retrofit`'s proxy mechanism, there will always be a `response` instance even if the response is an Http error. This means that calling `onNext` will still happen even if the response is an http error itself. You can have a look at the [parseReponse](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/OkHttpCall.java) method and as you see there's no exception thrown if the status code is 500.

Back to the observables, only when there's an exception will the subscriber's `onError` be called. Remember, if it's status code 500 there's no exception thrown.

To get your `onError` to fire for non 2XX http error codes there are different ways, but one possible way is to (if you can afford it) make your call return `Observable<Foo>` instead of `Observable<Response<Foo>>`.

This will make retrofit use internally different observables that will make sure to call your subscriber's `onError` when there's an http error as well as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Only network errorsare thrown into `onError` (e.g. no internet connection).

Think of a 500er as a valid response from the server instead of an error case. Furthermore you want to use the error information the server provided (Body, status code, Headers, etc.). `onError` can't provide this (unless as an Exception).

Comment: What I don't understand is that it seems 400 / 500 errors in other API calls seems to get routed to onError.

Comment: Maybe you didn't wrap the other API calls with `Response<..>`? Without Response wrapping all Errors will invoke `onError`

Comment: Just to complete it: If you wrap your Object into `Result<..>` every Request will invoke `onNext` even on Network errors.

Comment: I used retrofit-rxjava adapter. So the one that does get routed looks like Observable<Boolean> doSomething(); and the one that doesn't routed is defined as Observable<Response<Void>> doSomeOtherThing(); Are you saying the "wrapping" or rather the return type of the retrofit client declaration decides whether or not onError gets invoked on actual server error?

Comment: Yes! see the JavaDoc documentation here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java